# AngularJS duplicates http requests

Tags: javascript, http, angularjs

I'm doing some interfaces with AngularJS and watching the Chrome Console I detect that each http request to an API it makes for duplicate.
Is there any way to avoid this?

This is my simplified code

```
$http.jsonp('http://APIURL.com/api/category/menu?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){
    $scope.categories=data.categories;
});
```

Full code:

```
var kbControllers = angular.module('kbControllers', []);
kbControllers.controller("KBHomeController", function ($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.header = 'Title of page';
    $http.jsonp('apicall.com/api/category/menu?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function (data) {
        $scope.categories = data.categories;
    });
});
```

and this is my console
[image]

any thought?

Comment: I suspect that the logic that calls the API is what's actually firing twice. Can you share that code?

Comment: var kbControllers = angular.module('kbControllers', []);

    kbControllers.controller("KBHomeController", function ($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
 $rootScope.header = 'Title of page';

 $http.jsonp('http://apicall.com/api/category/menu?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
 .success(function(data){
  $scope.categories=data.categories;
 });
})

Comment: Everytime I encounter this it's because my listeners/watchers are firing a request multiple times.  Reorganize logic and should be good.  Trace through your code with console.log.

Comment: @MichaelCalkins can you translate for not advanced angularjs programme?

Comment: @juan Not knowing what your code looks like I'd try things link adding a `console.log()` message to all of the places where your $http functions are being called.  It's been my experience that when I find the spot that calls a $http function more than once I just need to modify that spot's condition that triggers the $http function.  The code you posted is perfect, the flow you take that calls that code is what usually is the issue.

Comment: @juan can you post more code? this snippet seems to be fine -- for sure the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Here more code, http://stackoverflow.com/a/20552587/604637

Answer (score 3):

i have faced this problem, and you can resolve it like this :

- check if you have declared ng-controller twice , you need to declare it just one time
- check if you have declared data-ng-click , if so , you need to replace it with ng-click

that's it

Comment: I was almost going crazy 'cause everything on one section was making double and repeated requests, thank you for advising me to check if I had declared the controller twice.

Answer (score -1):

This is app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
   'ngRoute','kbControllers', 'kbFilters', 'kbDirectives', 'angularytics', 'kbServices'
]).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/',
        {
            templateUrl: '/assets/angular/kb/partials/home.html',
            controller: 'KBHomeController'
        }
    ).when('/category/:category',
        {
            templateUrl: '/assets/angular/kb/partials/category.html',
            controller: 'KBCategoryController'
        }
    )
    .otherwise({redirectTo:"/"});
  }
])
```

And in controllers.js

```
var kbControllers = angular.module('kbControllers', []);

kbControllers.controller("KBHomeController", function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, Menu) {
$rootScope.header = 'Atención al cliente - Movistar Argentina';

    $http.jsonp('http://APIURL.com/api/category/menu?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data){
    $scope.categories=data.categories;
    });
})
```

and my view /partials/home.html

```
[...]
<li ng-repeat="category in categories"><a href="#/category/{{category.path}}"><i class="{{category.icon}}"></i><span>{{category.name}}</span></a></li>
[...]
```

Comment: seems to be something with jsonp, because changing to $http.get works fine.